# how to place buttons inside a layout at desired positions in android

Tags: android

I am new to android, In my project named Fill In the Blanks I have to place textviews and editboxes at desired positions in a layout . plz help me 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Read some basics about Android layouts: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html

Answer (score 0):

Start [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) to acquaint yourself with Android layout XML, then familiarise yourself with the various layout objects that are available by reading [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the desired positions.
There are several layouts you can use.

The link mibollma provided is a good start to learn the basics of layouts.

Here are some tutorials on some different layouts:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://www.droiddraw.org/  With fair easy GUI interface, it will create for you the XML needed for whatever GUI you will draw.

Answer (score 0):

You should use RelativeLayouts,they allow you to put widgets in any position without nesting too much(something that you gotta do with LinearLayouts)

Answer (score -2):

You should use AbsuluteLayout in android for place object on desired position.

Comment: AbosuteLayout is deprecated and will prevent your app from working across different screen sizes and densities.

Comment: Hello Mark please read the question properly they want to place object on desire place of the location means with the help of x and y coordinate.And we are also able to run a application build in absolutelayout with different device it is possible i have done it with the use of mathematically  percentage.

Comment: Still it is a bad practice that's not encouraged by the Android team.

Comment: Yes i know it is bad but i have given answer according to question requirement.Some time in game development it is need of Absolutelayout du to this google add it on our library other wise why it is add in the library tell me .